# Django + Angular 405 Method not allowed thinkster.io tutorial

Tags: python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am going through thinkster.io tutorial about Django and AngularJS. I am about half way of tutorial, but I am getting the error 405 Method not allowed for my POST request of user registration. I tried all sugestions but none of them seems to work ( I also tried to copying whole code from tutorial ). Here is my code:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import permissions, viewsets
from authentication.models import Account
from authentication.permissions import IsAccountOwner
from authentication.serializers import AccountSerializer


class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'username'
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

        return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(), IsAccountOwner(),)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            Account.objects.create_user(**serializer.validated_data)

            return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response({
            'status': 'Bad request',
            'message': 'Account could not be created with received data.'
        }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash

from rest_framework import serializers

from authentication.models import Account


class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
                  'first_name', 'last_name', 'tagline', 'password',
                  'confirm_password',)
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at',)

        def create(self, validated_data):
            return Account.objects.create(**validated_data)

        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
            instance.tagline = validated_data.get('tagline', instance.tagline)

            instance.save()

            password = validated_data.get('password', None)
            confirm_password = validated_data.get('confirm_password', None)

            if password and confirm_password and password == confirm_password:
                instance.set_password(password)
                instance.save()

            update_session_auth_hash(self.context.get('request'), instance)

            return instance
```

permissions.py

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsAccountOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, account):
        if request.user:
            return account == request.user
        return False
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

from thinkster_django_angular_boilerplate.views import IndexView

from rest_framework_nested import routers

from authentication.views import  AccountViewSet

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns(
     '',
    # ... URLs
    url(r'^/api/v1/', include(router.urls)),

    url('^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
)
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from django.db import models

class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid email address.')

        if not kwargs.get('username'):
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid username.')

        account = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email), username=kwargs.get('username')
        )

        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()

        return account

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        account = self.create_user(email, password, **kwargs)

        account.is_admin = True
        account.save()

        return account


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    tagline = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)

    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return ' '.join([self.first_name, self.last_name])

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name
```

I think the problem is with Django code, because AngularJS seems to not throw any errors and I can see that request is coming to the django. I am using python3.4, Django 1.8.3, and Django-rest-framework 3.1.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is causing your issue, but I think you need to remove the trailing slash from this line `router.register(r'accounts/', AccountViewSet)`. [The documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter) has a mention of the `trailing_slash` argument for routers, which could potentially be causing issues.

Comment: I removed it, still same error.